# How can I restore only a few lines from a file recorded in a given commit?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I want to restore a few lines from a file recorded in an older commit. I can see those lines by running

```
git log -p
```

As a last resort, I'm ready to simply copy those lines from the output of that log, but that would hurt my purist's heart and seems rather unprofessional.

I do *not* want to simply run `git checkout <file>` because that would discard local changes made to `<file>` since the commit in question. Instead, I would like to merge changes from that commit into `<file>` in the working tree using only pure Git commands.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use `git log` to figure out which commit removed those lines, then revert or partially revert that commit as needed.

Comment: @AndrewC "that would discard local changes made to <file> since the commit in question"

Comment: that's not how revert works in git.   Maybe you are thinking of svn? Or maybe you are thinking of git reset.

Comment: @AndrewC can you place an answer with *revert* ? I could choose that as accepted answer.

Comment: A month later? You have an answer with revert already.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Use interactive checkout

The following `git-checkout` syntax,

```
git checkout --patch <tree-ish> -- <paths>
```

or, equivalently,

```
git checkout -p <tree-ish> -- <paths>
```

allows you to interactively check out hunks from one or more files, listed in `<paths>`, as recorded in `<tree-ish>` (most commonly, a commit).

See the [`git-checkout` man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) for more details.

### Example

To fix ideas, here is a toy example (irrelevant stdout is omitted):

```sh
# set things up
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ git init

# create some content and commit
$ printf "Hello, world.\n" > README.md
$ printf "foo\nbar\nbaz\n" > test.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "initial commit"

# modify the working tree
$ printf "another line\n" >> README.md 
$ printf "foo\nfoo\n" > test.txt

# now restore stuff from test.txt as recorded in master's tip
$ git checkout -p master -- test.txt
diff --git b/test.txt a/test.txt
index 0d55bed..86e041d 100644
--- b/test.txt
+++ a/test.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 foo
-foo
+bar
+baz
Apply this hunk to index and worktree [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]? y
error: patch failed: test.txt:1
error: test.txt: patch does not apply
The selected hunks do not apply to the index!
Apply them to the worktree anyway? y

# Sanity check: inspect the working tree
# (the hunk "bar\nbaz" from test.txt was restored, as desired)
$ cat test.txt
foo
bar
baz
# (README.md, on the other hand, was not affected, as desired)
$ cat README.md
Hello, world.
another line
```

Answer (score 2):

If in the older commit you only changed this file, and you want to undo all those changes,
then simply do:

```
git revert SHA
```

If there were more than one files, here's a pure `git` (and not great) solution:

```
git revert SHA --no-commit
git reset
git add path/to/file
git checkout .
git commit
```

Or a `git` + `patch` solution (also not great):

```
git diff -p SHA path/to/file > patch
patch -R < patch
git commit .
```

Comment: I don't know... Interactive checkout seems like a more straightforward way of doing things, here.

Comment: You're humble :-) Yes, your interactive checkout method totally rocks, and a better answer in my opinion! +1