# How can partial changes from a previous commit be retrieved?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have the following scenario on a Git branch.

- Commit 1: `file1`, `file2`, `file3` added.
- Commit 2: `file1`, `file3` changed.
- Commit 3: `file2` changed.
- Commit 4: `file3` changed.

I now have uncommitted changes in `file2`, and I would like to retrieve some changes made to `file1` and `file3` in commit 2, and then create a fifth commit? How can I do that?

Comment: What if you rollback to commit 2 in a new branch? get the file content and then make changes in master branch and commit it.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to use [interactive checkout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27336028/how-can-i-restore-only-a-few-lines-from-a-file-recorded-in-a-given-commit/27336339#27336339) on files 1 and 3, then stage everything and commit.

Answer (score 0):

In order to "revert your files", you should do:

```
git checkout HEAD~2 file1
git checkout HEAD~2 file3
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, but I think the OP wants to only *partially* restore `file1` and `file3` as they're stored in `commit2`. What you're suggesting would restore the *entire* files.