# How do I get rid of the changes made to one file for a specific commit in Git?

Tags: git

I have one file that I should not have modified and I want to revert all the changes that I have made. However, I don't want to reset back to a specific branch, because in between the changes I made, I merged in changes made by others, so I only want to reverse the changes that I made.

Comment: Do you want to revert the changes made to all files since that commit, or just the changes made to one specific file?

Comment: Just the ones to that one specific file. And not all changes, a list of specific changes for which I've listed the SHA's.

Comment: I can do them one-by-one. I just haven't found an answer on StackExchange that tells me how to do that.

Comment: Have you heard of [interactive checkout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27336028/how-can-i-restore-only-a-few-lines-from-a-file-recorded-in-a-given-commit/27336339#27336339)? I think that would be the simplest approach.

Comment: Is there a way to just get rid of the changes from a single commit? I want my git to not record that I've made any changes to that file.

Comment: No. Once created, commits are set in stone. You would have to use something like `git rebase` for that, and that may not even be a good idea, if you've made your code available on a shared remote.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be:

- Make a commit that fixes the problem (if in a single commit, you could do this with `git revert`)
- `git rebase -i` passing the commit before the problematic commit
- Reorder the commits so the revert is immediately after the problematic commit
- Check that works
- Now use `git rebase -i` again and either squash the two commits or if they are exact opposites just delete both of them

I suggest doing this on a test branch first.