# How to revert a single line non-interactively?

Tags: git, command-line-interface

How do I revert a single line changed in Git without the interactive mode?
(for interactive there's [How can I restore only a few lines from a file recorded in a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27336028/how-can-i-restore-only-a-few-lines-from-a-file-recorded-in-a-given-commit)).

I need something like:

```
 git checkout -line 107 src/main/MyPreciousFile.txt
```

I am OK with using some 3rd party tools.

Comment: If you consider an IDE to be a third party tool, then there is a simple solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question can be interpreted in two ways which have different solutions.

### Revert Hunk Touching Specific Line

The `grepdiff` command can be used to select a hunk out of a diff that matches certain criteria (hunk index, line numbers, content, ...). In this case it can be used to limit a diff to the hunks including a specific line number. The resulting (reverse) hunk is then sent to `patch` to be applied:

```
$ git diff -U0 -R -- src/main/MyPreciousFile.txt \
    | grepdiff --lines=107 --output-matching=hunk . \
    | patch -p1
```

This generates a reverse diff of the file, filters out the hunk touching the desired line and applies the resulting patch.

This can be packaged into a shell function:

```
$ function revert_hunk_touching_line() {
    git diff -U0 -R -- "$1" \
        | grepdiff --lines="$2" --output-matching=hunk . \
        | patch -p1        
}
$ revert_hunk_touching_line src/main/MyPreciousFile.txt 107
```

Note that the specified line number is with regard to the current file. If the line number should reference a line in the original, the reversing needs to happen on the other end:

```
$ git diff -U0 -- src/main/MyPreciousFile.txt \
    | grepdiff --lines=107 --output-matching=hunk . \
    | patch -p1 -R
```

### Blindly Replace Specific Line from Orignal

If the goal is to simply replace the line number `x` in the current file with the line number `x` from the original file, a function using `sed` can be made:

```
$ function revert_line() {
    sed -i "${2}c\\$(git show ":$1" | sed "${2}q;d")" "$1"
}
$ revert_line src/main/MyPreciousFile.txt 107
```

This edits the desired file (in-place) to replace the desired line with the corresponding line extracted from the original file.

Note that this does not take into account that the line in the current file may not be at the same spot as in the original (due to added/removed lines in between). It will also fail if the line itself is an addition or removal.

Comment: That worked. I only needed to add `--no-color` to `git diff` calls (that's due to my global git settings). Otherwise it wouldn't work.